# How to set specific start time in reduceByKeyAndWindow?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm working with Spark Streaming and I am consuming a Kafka topic, also I have defined a streaming window with reduceByKeyAndWindow and when I put for example windowLength 10 seconds with slideInterval 10 seconds, I get the results every 10 seconds as expected, the problem is that I want the window to be shown every 10 seconds starting at a specific time, at 00 seconds, no matter the minute, so that at 10,20,30, etc I get the results, because now I get the results every 10 seconds but in one execution the window starts for example in 01, 11, 21, and in another executing 09,19,29, etc.

Does anyone know how I can force the window to start at the second I want?

Thanks!